# Why does adding borders to a div cause vertical scrolling on a phone

Tags: html, css, responsive

I feel dumb for not being to figure this out. I have a very simple bit of HTML:

```
<body>
    <div style="border: 40px solid red"></div>
    <div style="border: 40px solid green"></div>
</body>
```

There is no additional css. This simply creates two empty `div`s with thick `border`s around them.

When I load this on a phone, I am able to vertically scroll down the page a small amount. There is nothing down there. What is generating this vertical scrolling?

[Here's a fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/cplindem/1w1c1q1q/2/)

And a [full screen embedded version](http://jsfiddle.net/cplindem/1w1c1q1q/2/embedded/result/) to try viewing on a phone

I get the same effect whether I view on an actual phone or in Chrome's developer tools (in phone view).

**Edit** Now using `border`s that will fit within a phone's viewport - the scrolling sill occurs.

Comment: Is the phone viewport exactly 800px tall? The `body` element does have some margin by default; does adding `body { margin: 0; }` to your css help?

Comment: try adding this: margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;

Comment: You can use overflow-y: auto if you want vertical scrolling. and if you want horizontal scrolling, you can even use overflow-x: auto; Or you can disable that by using overflow: none;

Comment: I actually didn't clearly understand your question. Do you want the scrolling to happen or you don't want it? :)

Comment: setting margins and padding to zero doesn't seem to change anything (same with box-sizing). My phone viewport is smaller than 800px tall (and wide), but it seems to zoom out to fit it. Oddly, this does not generate squarish borders, but instead horizontally oriented rectangles. The full width upon inspection shows 980 or 964px. Then it shows white space below, plus more white space upon scrolling, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: I'm just looking to understand why scrolling is happening in the first place. There is no additional content at the bottom of the page, so why am I allowed to scroll down?

Comment: 200px border top + 200px border bottom + 200px border top + 200px border bottom is 800px. Borders may not be content but they do have a specific size; if they add up to more than the viewport is tall why *wouldn't* it scroll? As for being a rectangle, by default a `div` will fill the viewport width so if your viewport isn't a square then they will end up as rectangles.

Comment: the screen is zooming out to make it fit (width-wise). There is only white space below. There is nothing to scroll to. Perhaps this will simplify things: http://jsfiddle.net/cplindem/1w1c1q1q/2/embedded/result/ That fiddle only has 40px borders but the scrolling still occurs.

Comment: Did you set the height of the body of the html?

Comment: I have not set the height of the body. The only html or css I have is posted above. And it's all visible in the fiddle. Just look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the [responsive meta tag](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

would be nice to add also `margin:0` to `body` and `box-sizing:border-box` to `*`

something like this:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
.b {
  border: 40px solid
}
.red {
  border-color: red
}
.green {
  border-color: green
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<body>
  <div class="b red"></div>
  <div class="b green"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. The responsive meta tag was indeed the issue. I'm surprised jsfiddle doesn't add that. Or at least give you the ability to add it yourself.